# vbaProject.bin File in my Powerpoint Presentation Corrupted after running code to move Slides to different Presentation

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I've been working on VBA code to automate moving sections of a Presentation to different .pptm files. This has had a couple of issues.
Firstly, if too many sections are moved in a row (at around 13/14 sections with 10-20 slides each) the code crashes with various errors such as insufficient memory being available.

Secondly, after using this code once with a bug and after saving and closing the presentation, the vbaProject was not visible in the VBA editor and seems to be corrupted. When inspecting the pptm file with 7z the vbaProject.bin was still in the file and even if moved to another uncorrupted .pptm file the vbaProject will not show up in the VBA editor.

Is there a way to extract the VBA code from the uncorrupted files? If someone here is knowledgable about this kind of issue, I can provide you with the corrupted vbaProject.bin if there are ways of fixing it.

Comment: One way is to open the project with LibreOffice and copy it from there (you will have to remove `Rem` at the beginning of each line)

Comment: I had again this issue and [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67666790/18247317) worked perfectly (much easier than what I suggested)